# I can't select my local package in Asset Store Tools

Tags: unity, assets

I made a local package and I'm trying to upload it to the AssetStore.
-My package is stored in the [root]/Packages folder.
-My Demo scene is stored in the [root]/Assets folder.

When I try to upload my package in the Asset Store Tools, I've an error if I select my sources in the Packages folder.
If i select my Demo scene folder instead, I have no error. But I don't want to upload only my Demo scene.
If I check 'include dependecies' it only add a json manifest file.

The error message is : *The path selected must be inside the currently active project.*

All answers about this error on google didn't helped me.
-Set the package as a Full project => I made a tool not a full project.
-The Project have to be in C:\ Hard drive => it is.
-The Project folder must have the package's name => it is. My project folder's name PropertyInterface as my asset.

I'm using Unity 2019.1.0f2.

It's the first time i try to upload my work in the Asset store. I'm pretty confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if this is possible at all at this time. I couldn't find any source that claims it is possible. But since you are talking about a local package, maybe you'll have more luck with an embedded package... See [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html#EmbedMe) and [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-embed.html). If this fails, or if you just want to know for sure, you might want to contact Unity Support, explain to them what you have, why you want to upload it as a package and whether it is possible. And then share the answer with us :)

Comment: Looking further into it, I did find a source that claims it is [not possible](https://forum.unity.com/threads/eta-of-asset-store-supports-package-manager.533309/#post-5569438) at this time ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I made my tool as a package to not use the "old ".unitypackage" format and to free some space in my asset folder. So if we can't share our package, i don't realy understand what it is for. :s

Answer (score 0):

Sadly as @Troien said : It's not possible to upload your local or embedded package in the asset store as [root]/Packages folder content.

> Looking further into it, I did find a source that claims it is [not possible](https://forum.unity.com/threads/eta-of-asset-store-supports-package-manager.533309/#post-5569438) at this time ;) – troien yesterday

To upload it, you need to store it in the [root]/Assets folder. I recommand to use [root]/Assets/Plugins/[YourAssetName] as hierarchy.
If you do that you should delete your manifest and '.asmdef' files.